# How do I check if a key is down in XNA when I'm only given a string that has the key's name?

Tags: c#, xna, code-reflection, metaprogramming

I'm trying to get access to the keyboard state in XNA from an embedded JavaScript runtime.

I'd like to do something similar to the following, but I can't seem to figure out how to get from "Left" to Keys.Left, in one line, for all 100+ keys or so.

```
js.SetParameter("XNA_Keyboard", new {
    keyDown = (Func<string, bool>)((name) => {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys[name]); // ! Can't index keys enum by name
    }),
});
```

Is there some kind of reflection that will make this easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
js.SetParameter("XNA_Keyboard", new {
    keyDown = (Func<string, bool>)((name) => {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown((Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), name, false)); // ! Can't index keys enum by name
    }),
});
```

That should do the trick, assuming the names match the C# ones.